# NSManagedObject associatedtype has no member 'fetchRequest' in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

After upgrading to Xcode 13, I am seeing compilation issues with the below code:

```
public protocol CoreDataFetchable {
    associatedtype FetchableObject: NSManagedObject

    static func fetchFromCoreData(withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?) -> Array<Self>
}

extension CoreDataFetchable {
    
    static public func fetchFromCoreData(withPredicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> Array<Self> {
        let context = ...
        let fetchRequest = FetchableObject.fetchRequest()
        ...
        return [Self]()
    }
}
```

The following line:
`let fetchRequest = FetchableObject.fetchRequest()`
results in the following compilation error message:
`Type 'Self.FetchableObject' has no member 'fetchRequest'`

If anyone has any insight into this I'd be much obliged :)

Comment: Compiles in a playground.

Comment: `After upgrading to Xcode 13` - did it work on Xcode12?

Comment: Did you found fix for this?

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for the same?

Comment: There most be something more to it than what is presented here since it isn't reproducible. Maybe you guys who are asking if it is fixed could contribute with something. @NaimishKaria

Comment: Working fine on Xcode 13.0

Comment: After simplification of provided snapshot to request-only dependent code all compiled fine with Xcode 13, so I assume this was either in beta or originated from some other code.

Comment: You'll get that error if you haven't imported `CoreData`, but you'll also get the following error: `error: cannot find type 'NSManagedObject' in scope` which is pretty hard to ignore. Are you also receiving that error?